# Microsoft Bot Framework - which extensions in VS?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, bots, botframework

please, I am very new with Visual Studio. I just downloaded the basic pack (less than 1Gb) and I just want to know which of the the extensions and packages I need to add to start working with Bot Framework using C#/ .Net.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here's a heads-up for you start [Bot Framework C# Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-overview). Happy learning :)

Comment: Thank you my friend. I just realized I need a new laptop before starting with that. I will come back in few days ;)

Answer (score 3):

For VS extensions, you will need to open **visual studio installer** and then install the **ASP.NET and web development** extension which belongs to Web & Cloud part, cause a .net based bot is actually a web application.

Then you may download the [Bot template for Visual Studio](http://aka.ms/bf-bc-vstemplate) here so for directly creating a application with botframework in VS, to integrate this bot template with your VS, you may refer to [How to: Locate and organize project and item templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-locate-and-organize-project-and-item-templates), the template should be placed for example in the following folder:

> %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio \Templates\ProjectTemplates

Then as @Kunal Mukherjee suggested, you may refer to [Bot Builder SDK for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-overview) to get start with your bot.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! Right now, I need a new laptop before starting with this new journey. I will come back in few days!